# How do i change the Encoding of my BBjServices?

Tags: bbj

My BBjServices have a different encoding. This causes my Data from the Database to be displayed wrong.
Where can i change the encoding of the Services ?

Answer (score 1):

In your BBj installation and open the `BBj.properties` in the `cfg` folder and search for `basis.java.args.BBjServices`
This already has a lot of values set. You want to add or change
`-Dfile.encoding="Your encoding".`

Remember to shut down the services first and restart them afterward.